# Angular 4 - create new Child Component in Parent with DI

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular2-services

I have an array of child components which are displayed with an *ngFor.
My child components now require a DataService to be injected. How do I create a new ChildComponent() when the compiler now complains about needing an instance of the DataService for the constructor?

Parent Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {SkipComponent} from "../skip/skip.component";
import { DataService } from '../services/data.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-skips',
  templateUrl: './skips.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./skips.component.css'],
  providers: [ DataService ]
})
export class SkipsComponent implements OnInit {

  public childItems: SkipComponent[] = [new SkipComponent()];

  public removeSkip(skip){

    var index = this.childItems.findIndex((elt) => (elt===skip));
    if (index != -1) {
      this.childItems.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }

  public onAdd(){
    this.childItems.push(new SkipComponent());
  }

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
```

Child Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, Input, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../services/data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-skip',
  templateUrl: './skip.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./skip.component.css'],
  providers: [ DataService ]
})
export class SkipComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() skip: any;

  @Output()
  onSkipRemove: EventEmitter<any> =  new EventEmitter();

  containers: any[];

  public removeSkip(){
    this.onSkipRemove.emit(
      this.skip
     )
  }

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
    this.dataService.getContainers().subscribe(res=>this.containers=res);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The DI happens when instantiated by the framework, when you explicitly instantiate a `SkipComponent` with the `new` operator, you need to pass in the service. So your solution will be:

In the top level (`SkipsComponent`) get a hold of the `DataService`:

```
constructor(private dataServices: DataService){}
```

and then when you create `SkipComponent` pass it to the constructor:

```
this.childItems.push(new SkipComponent(this.dataService));
```